# How To Play MP4 With The Processbar Invisible

Tags: cmd, mp4

I want to play a file called startup.mp4 in command prompt but without the pause/play and the process bar of the video like in the **chilledwindows.exe** virus it plays a video but the user cannot notice that its a video. Is it possible if it is how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk --no-first-run --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --kiosk-idle-timeout-minutes=1 "https://ia800907.us.archive.org/9/items/Chillled_Windows/chilledwindows.mp4"
```

[image]

I added `--kiosk-idle-timeout-minutes=1` in case anyone gets into panic mode and hits every key apart from the close combination, just wait 60 seconds for a choice to appear.

For more options see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#use-kiosk-mode-features